# Sending large files over UDP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

Im trying to create app that will allow for client to upload file to server and for now im using UDP socket.

Im sending data over UDP and it works for small size file, and when i try to send like 1 MB it doesn't send full data.

I've read that UDP can only handle about 64kB packet, is it true? Can i somehow handle it and fix my problem?

My code for sending files:

```
        sendto(fdsocket, sizeBuff, sizeof(sizeBuff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, addrlen); // send file size
            while(1) {
                //Read file in chunks of 1024 bytes
                int nread = fread(buff, 1, BUFF_SIZE, filefp);

                printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);


                // If read was success, send data

                if(nread > 0){
                    printf("Sending file ...\n");

                    int n = sendto(fdsocket, buff, strlen(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, addrlen);
```

and my code for receiving files:

```
        recvfrom(fdsocket, sizeBuff, sizeof(sizeBuff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, &addrlen); // recv file size
        filesize = sizeBuff[0];
        printf("Filesize: %lu", filesize);

        //recvfrom(fdsocket, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, &addrlen);

        if(sizeBuff[0] > 0){
            while(sumBytes<filesize){
                /* Receive data in chunks of 1024 bytes */
                bytesReceived = recvfrom(fdsocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, &addrlen);
                if(bytesReceived < 0) {
                    printf("Recvfrom: Error in receiving the file\n");
                    exit(1);
                } else {
                    sumBytes = sumBytes + bytesReceived;
                    printf("Bytes received: %d\n", sumBytes);
                }
                if(fwrite(buff, 1, bytesReceived, fp)<0){
                    printf("ERROR writing file");
                    exit(1);
                }
```

I want it to work with big files, like 100MB, and also allow me to send jpg, xls and other.

How can i do that? Will switching to TCP solve my problem?

Comment: There's already a standard protocol for this: [TFTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350)

Comment: "*for now im using UDP socket*" - why did you choose UDP and not TCP?

Comment: If your goal is simply to transfer files (and not e.g. to learn about how to transfer files using UDP) then using TCP will be much less work than using UDP.

Comment: "I've read that UDP can only handle about 64kB packet, is it true?" No it isn't. The maximum UDP payload is 65507 bytes, and the maximum *practical* payload is 534 bytes or thereabouts.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that UDP can only handle about 64kB packet, is it true?

Yes. So you will have to break up larger files into smaller packets and send them individually. And know that UDP is unreliable - packet delivery is not guaranteed at all, and packets are not guaranteed to arrive in the same order in which they are sent - so you have to add reliability into your transfer protocol - send back ACKs for received packets, use sequence numbers in each packet, etc, so the receiver knows which packets go in which order, and the sender can know which packets the receiver is missing so they can be resent.

> Will switching to TCP solve my problem?

Yes, as it has delivery and integrity guarantees built in.  Though, UDP *can* work, too (protocols like [Trivial FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) are proof of that).

Answer (score 1):

UDP is an unreliable protocol.  If a packet gets lost you need a way for the receiver to inform the sender so it can retransmit the packet.  The receiver also needs to allow for packets to be received out of order.

Using TCP will solve this for you, since it has reliability built in and data is guaranteed to arrive in order.

Adding this reliability to UDP is not trivial but it can be done.  Shameless plug: [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net/) does this and supports multicast.

Answer (score 1):

Sending files over UDP is good in localhost, I was trying in public IP, it's good for when the data has possibility loss tolerated. So if the data is important and must be completely sent 100%, better use TCP.

So if you still insist sending files over UDP, I assume your network is reliable such as LAN or better internet throughput.

Like @RemyLebeau answer, you must send packet per packet into smaller chunk. In this case my payload size/packet size (UDP_BUF_SIZE) is `1357` bytes. I chose 1357 because youtube UDP buffer size is 1357 too when I analyzed it in wireshark during streaming any video, another reason is probably MTU in internet is `1500` bytes. If UDP_BUF_SIZE larger than MTU, probably IP Fragmentation occurs. So if you have `4096` bytes file size, the packet will be splitted into

- #1 packet's size is 1357 to send
- #2 packet's size 1357 to send
- #3 packet's size 1357 to send
- #4 packet's size 25 to send

This is implementation in code in sender side:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UDP_BUF_SIZE 1357 // Following youtube buffer size.

int main(void) {

  // Moving file from storage into memory (variabel buff)
  FILE *fp;
  size_t bufsz;
  fp = fopen("./2MB-image.jpg", "r");
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  bufsz = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  printf("File size: %li bytes\n", bufsz);
  char buff[bufsz];
  fread(buff, sizeof(char), bufsz, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  // Initializing UDP Sender
  struct sockaddr_in receiverAddr;
  receiverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
  receiverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  receiverAddr.sin_port = htons(39876);
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  // Actual sending...
  char *from = &buff[0]; // Start of file
  size_t remainingToSend = bufsz; // File size
  while (remainingToSend > 0) { //do it until no remaining bytes to send.
    size_t sendSize =
        remainingToSend > UDP_BUF_SIZE ? UDP_BUF_SIZE : remainingToSend;
    while (sendto(sockfd, (const char *)from, sendSize, 0,
                  (const struct sockaddr *)&receiverAddr,
                  sizeof(receiverAddr)) < 0) { // Sending packet per packet
      printf("Error during send, retrying...\n");
    }
    remainingToSend -= sendSize;
    from += sendSize;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please make sure when you answer that you read the previous answers and ensure that your answer is adding new information. For more information see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: How does this code recover when a UDP packet gets dropped or received out-of-sequence?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I have no idea since UDP has no detail header unlike TCP. My code looks like burst transmission. But it can be customizable protocol like allocating first two bytes for sequence number to prevent out-of-sequence. For packet gets dropped prevention, maybe receiver must send 1byte  ACK packet every 2 packet received.